# Why does this grep statement do the opposite of what I expect?

Tags: linux, grep, text, html, whitespace

I have a file with some HTML and some text mixed in, I just wanted to use the text lines.

I was fooling around with `grep`, trying to get a way to exclude the lines that began with an HTML tag, even lines that included whitespace before the tag.

Somehow this works for me, but I don't think it should:

`grep '^\<' file.htm`

It just shows me the lines without html. Can you explain why? I thought I would need `grep -v` and some `.*` somewhere to make this work.

Comment: Remember when fooling around that in the general case, when usage gets serious, arbitrary HTML cannot be parsed with regular expressions.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/1758162/340790

Answer (score 15):

From [GNU `grep` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html):

> `\<`
> Match the empty string at the beginning of word.
>
> `\>`
> Match the empty string at the end of word.

This is also relevant [emphasis mine]:

> `-w`
> `--word-regexp`
> Select only those lines containing matches that form whole words. The test is that the matching substring must either be at the beginning of the line, or preceded by a non-word constituent character. Similarly, it must be either at the end of the line or followed by a non-word constituent character. **Word constituent characters are letters, digits, and the underscore.** […]
>
> Because the `-w` option can match a substring that does not begin and end with word constituents, it differs from surrounding a regular expression with `\<` and `\>`. For example, although `grep -w @` matches a line containing only `@`, `grep '\<@\>'` cannot match any line because `@` is not a word constituent. […]

And for completeness:

> The caret `^` and the dollar sign `$` are meta-characters that respectively match the empty string at the beginning and end of a line. They are termed anchors, since they force the match to be “anchored” to beginning or end of a line, respectively.

The pattern you used (`^\<`) matches the beginning of a line just before a word constituent character. Neither `<` character nor whitespace is a word constituent.

Note a whitespace at the beginning of a line will not trigger a match, *regardless* if there's a tag or something else right after. Some characters valid for text lines will not trigger a match either (e.g. `(`).

Comment: @pLumo, don't even need the brackets, just `grep '<'` is enough as `<` isn't special in itself. Aside: Perl is nicer here, in that backslashing a non-letter always makes it match literally, and all the magic matches are backslash-letter.

Comment: @ikkachu The Perl rule is much better in this regard, but you've omitted half of it: Any escaped special char is literal, and any un-escaped alphanumeric is literal. Don't forget that `+` and `(` are non-literal in Perl.